# Uniform behaviour of limit infimum

Tags: real-analysis, potential-theory

Let $f$ and $f_n,n=1,2,\dots$ be real valued function on domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb C$. Then what is mean by
$$f(x) \leq \liminf_{n \to \infty}f_n(x)$$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\Omega?$

This appeared in **’Logarithmic potentials with external fields’** by Saff and Totik (Page no. 71).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further context I am gonna have to assume "uniform" means "uniform with respect to $n$", in which case it can be rephrased as follows:

For every compact subset $K\subset\Omega$,
$$\forall\varepsilon>0,\exists N\in\mathbb Z^+,{\rm s.t. }\ \forall x\in K,\ f(x)\leq\inf_{k\geq N}f_k(x)+\varepsilon$$

"Uniform" means that $N$ is independent of $x$, as long as you only consider $x\in K$. However, $N$ may depend on $K$ and $\varepsilon$.

Comment: I had same guess. Could you tell what does it means if equality is there instead of $\leq$ sign in above equation?

Comment: @MayureshL In that case, replace the inequality in my answer by "$\forall n>N,\ |f(x)-\inf_{k\geq n}f_k(x)|<\varepsilon$". However you should definitely check whether this is consistent with the rest of the book. If so then it's most like to be right.

Comment: @MayureshL Also, the reason why I didn't add "$\forall n>N$" in my original answer is that $\inf_{k\geq n}f_k(x)$ is increasing w.r.t. $n$, and your original question was about an inequality, hence "$\forall n>N$" can be omitted.